# Fixnum class method modification

Tags: ruby

This is a description of a code kata that I'm working on for code wars. The aim of the kata is to accomplish this:

---

The aim of this Kata is to modify the Fixnum class to give it the palindrome_below method. This method returns all numbers from and including 1 up to but not including itself that are palindromes for a given base.

For example in base 2 (binary)

```
 1 = "1"
 2 = "10"
 3 = "11"
 4 = "100"
```

Therefore 1 and 3 are palindromes in base two and the method should return the following.

```
5.palindrome_below(2)
=> [1, 3]
```

---

Here is the code that I wrote so far for this kata:

```
class Fixnum
  def self.palindrome_below(binary)
    palindrome_match = []
    until self == 0
      if to_s(binary) == to_s(binary).reverse
       palindrome_match << self
       self -= 1
      end
    end
    palindrome_match
  end
end
```

I tried to decrease `self` by `1`. Sublime is telling me that I'm not able to decrease the value of `self` but I need to reduce `self`. Because this is a class method, I need to modify `self`.

This is what I tried as a work around:

```
class Fixnum
  def self.palindrome_below(binary)
    palindrome_match = []
    self_placeholder = self
    until self_placeholder == 0
      if self_placeholder.to_s(binary) == self_placeholder.to_s(binary).reverse
        palindrome_match << self_placeholder
        self_placeholder -= 1
      end
    end
    palindrome_match
  end
end
```

This time, I placed `self` in a wrapper variable so I could modify it. When I try this, it says that there is an undefined method called `palindrome_below`. Doing this implementation should have monkey patched `Fixnum`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: No problem. You can find it here http://www.codewars.com/kata/530d0298e09e54a3620006c2/train/ruby You might need to sign up/in though.

Comment: As @sawa said, you undoubtedly want an instance method, as you have in your example: `5.palindrome_below(2)`. There's no need to alter `self`, and in fact you couldn't even if you wanted to. (The only ways to change `self` are to invoke a method or create a class or module.) Try this: `def palendrome(base); 1.upto(self-1).select { |n| ....}`. `1` to `self-1` will be passed into the block and assigned to the block variable `n`.  You must add an expression to the block that returns `true` if and only `n` evaluates to a palendrome, for the given value of the parameter `base`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I think your solution is much better than the accepted answer - why didn't you post it as one?

Comment: Thanks, @Uri, but I didn't have enough time to post a proper answer.  If it helps, that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A Working Solution (based your second attempt above):

```
class Fixnum
    def palindrome_below(base)
        palindrome_match = []
        num = self - 1
        until num == 0
            if num.to_s(base) == num.to_s(base).reverse
                palindrome_match << num
            end
            num -= 1
        end
       palindrome_match.reverse
    end
end
```

What I changed:

1. You were right in adding a `self_placeholder` -- I named this variable `num`. In Ruby, `Fixnum`s are immutable, so you can't change the value of the particular `Fixnum` itself.

   - I subtracted 1 from `num` right at the beginning, so as to avoid including the number itself in the result array
2. `palindrome_below(base)` needs to be an instance method. You very much care about the value of the specific instance of the Fixnum class (ie., the value of the number).
3. You need to subtract 1 from `num` outside your `if` statement.
4. I reversed the `palindrome_match` array so that it returns in the proper ascending order.

### A Far Superior Solution (courtesy of @CarySwoveland's comment above).

```
class Fixnum
    def palindrome_below(base)
        1.upto(self-1).select { |num| num.to_s(base) == num.to_s(base).reverse }
    end
end
```